# Хранение ключей шифрования Aes в таблицах mysql

Tags: шифрование

Озадачился шифрованием конфиденциальных данных с возможностью дешифровки и последующей выдачи при определенных условиях. Выбрал библиотеку libsodium, т.к mcrypt в последней версии php не поддерживается. При добавлении юзера генерится ключ и добавляется в базу, далее при получении ключа из базы значения до и после не совпадают. Подозреваю, что дело в кодировке символов, подскажите плиз способ хранения ключей в базе, и способ разделения приватного и публичного полученного  с помощью libsodium. Заранее спасибо, сорри за глупый вопрос.

Comment: *при получении ключа из базы значения до и после не совпадают* Значит, выбран неверный тип поля. Для бинарных данных следует использовать BLOB - к полям этого типа никакие перекодировки не применяются (во всяком случае SQL-сервером).

Comment: *способ разделения приватного и публичного* Два ключа? значит, два поля...